# networking with epoll: error handling

Tags: c, networking, epoll

I am working on a networking application, written in C, using the Linux epoll facility. *I am indeed implementing my own event loop, and yes, I know there are libraries that do this for me. This is just an exercise, however, and I _want_ to implement the event loop myself.*

I was wondering about how to tackle error handling, specifically handling errors returned by epoll system calls. Should I really check for each return value? Because, it seems to me that some of the errors returned by e. g. `epoll_ctl` are *logic errors* rather than *runtime errors*; I mean, the only time I saw `epoll_ctl` fail was when I accidentally fed it an illegal epoll file descriptor or something else that only occurs when you write incorrect code. **So my question is, can** `epoll_ctl` **actually return a 'runtime error', like, say,** `write` **does when a pipe is broken?** If so, is it something I should check for? I do not intend to check for errors that indicate the kernel has run out of resources or stuff like that (in that case, what could one even do?). Additional question: can `fcntl` produce a runtime error of some sort when it is only used to set some flags (`O_NONBLOCK`)?

Comment: "When you're sure code works as intended, logic errors can be ignored, right?" <- this sort of logic is the road to code that fails miserably, with no useful diagnostics whatsoever, under maintenance. And doesn't port well. Possibly breaks with OS/library updates, again with no useful diagnostics.

Comment: @Mat +1 Agreed. I'll remove that remark, but still, my question remains whether these syscalls can produce runtime errors, so I can at least know what I'm dealing with. I need to treat runtime errors, errors that I have no control over whatsoever, extra carefully to keep the code robust, that's all.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already know that these calls can generate "runtime errors" as you call them - when limits are exceeded. Then you say you'll ignore those, but want robust code. That's contradictory.

Comment: I guess this answers my question. I'll just have to watch out for any error, then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `epoll` can return a runtime error.

From the manpage:

> ERRORS
>
> `EBADF`  `epfd` or `fd` is not a valid file descriptor.
>
> `EEXIST` op was `EPOLL_CTL_ADD`, and the supplied file descriptor `fd` is already registered with this epoll instance.
>
> `EINVAL` epfd is not an epoll file descriptor, or `fd` is the same as `epfd`, or the requested operation op is not supported by this interface.
>
> `ENOENT` op was `EPOLL_CTL_MOD` or `EPOLL_CTL_DEL`, and `fd` is not registered with this `epoll` instance.
>
> `ENOMEM` There was insufficient memory to handle the requested op control operation.
>
> `ENOSPC` The limit imposed by `/proc/sys/fs/epoll/max_user_watches` was encountered while trying to register (`EPOLL_CTL_ADD`) a new file  descriptor  on  an  epoll  instance. See `epoll`(7) for further details.
>
> `EPERM`  The target file `fd` does not support `epoll`.

As you can see, `ENOMEM` and `ENOSPC` are runtime errors. Depending on your logic, `EPERM` might also be a runtime error (e.g. if you are incorporating stdin into `epoll` and there is a redirect).

However, good practice suggests you check anyway - far better to fail early if you have a logic error.